# Translating Python 2 code to Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib2, cookielib, python-2to3

Can anybody help me translating this python 2 code to python 3 without using the 2to3 tool ?

```
import urllib2, cookielib
self.cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(self.cookie_file)
self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(
            urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
            urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
            urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
            urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer myself via Python docs:

```
import http.cookiejar
import urllib.request
self.cj = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar(self.cookie_file)
self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
            urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
            urllib.request.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
            urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),
            urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj)
        )
```